# calling an function from another page is not working (ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and I have a simple function which takes to parameters and returns the result of adding those to up:

```
function DoMath(p1, p2) {
  try {
    return p1 + p2;
  } catch (exception) {
    return "sorry, worng output do you want to try again?"
  }
}
```

This function is located it the file `app.js`.

I also  added export of the function: `module.exports.DoMath=addTowPharmetrs;`

In other file, called `app2.js`, i am trying to give to parameters to the function and call it:

```
var key=require("./app.js");
var output=key.addTowPharmetrs(5, 1);
/*expected output: 6*/
console.log(output);
```

However, the program is not running with the error:

> ReferenceError: addTowPharmetrs is not defined

What should I do in order to fix it and make it work?

Comment: Why would `addTowPharmetrs` work? You named it `DoMath`. Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the property name with the local variable name:

```
module.exports.DoMath=addTowPharmetrs;
```

should be

```
module.exports.addTowPharmetrs = DoMath;
```